# Install native-bzip2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hadoop, bzip2

I have recently tried to build Hadoop 2.4 to use it's native libraries.

And when I check that if hadoop is really using it. I get the following warning :

```
 WARN bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
```

So I tried to look for the native-bzip2 library with `apt-cache` and I got the following :

```
lib32bz2-1.0 - high-quality block-sorting file compressor library - 32bit runtime
libbz2-1.0 - high-quality block-sorting file compressor library - runtime
lib64bz2-1.0 - high-quality block-sorting file compressor library - 64bit runtime
```

I have tried to install `lib64bz2-1.0` and `libbz2-1.0` but both didn't contains the native-bzip2 library.

Any suggestion on how to do it is welcome? Or even any explanation that what I am trying to do is a complete non-sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be couple of discussion concerning this topic on JIRA :

The first one discussing how the message error isn't clear [Bzip2 error message isn't clear](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10409) and so there is not resolution for it besides updating the documentation on it's concern.

It seems like BUILDING.txt is missing some information about native compression libraries. Noticeably if you are missing zlib/bzip2/snappy devel libraries, those will get silently skipped unless you pass the -Drequire.$LIB option (e.x. -Drequire.snappy). [Ref. [JIRA issue.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10452)]

The correction should be release with Hadoop 2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to install development files and static libraries before compiling Hadoop.
Try to install libbz2-dev before compiling.

Comment: I have already done that and it's still not working